# conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string nvarchar to nvarchar

Tags: t-sql

Crazy error here. I'm selecting a load of data from a customer table which is held in `nvarchar` datatype and I am then trying to insert this into another table of datatype `nvarchar`.

```
INSERT INTO NameSplit (B@, Ref@, FirstName, MiddleNames, Surname, Title)
select B@
      ,Ref@
      ,FirstName
      ,MiddleNames
      ,Surname
      ,NewTitle
from #2
```

but for some reason it is trying to convert this when it is inserting it into my new table, it starts off in nvarchar and ends up going into nvarchar.

Yes this has bad data in there and someone has put dates etc in the name fields, but i still dont get how this is being looked at in a datetime fashion??

Thanks

Comment: Please supply the `CREATE TABLE` definition of `NameSplit` and also any insert triggers on the table?

Comment: check to see if you have a trigger

Comment: Trigger it was, thank you!!!